# Subset a dataframe excluding rows in another dataframe

Tags: r

I'm trying to build multiple datasets for cross-validation using a loop in R. I have the following code:

```
for (i in 1:10) {
  as.data.frame(assign(paste("c",i,sep="_"),dd[((100*i)-99):(100*i),]))
  as.data.frame(assign(paste("t",i,sep="_"),subset(dd,-c_[[i]])))     
}
```

So, the first line in the loop works and correctly creates my control sets, but I can't seem to figure out how to create the training sets as a subset of my initial data that excludes the rows in the control sets.

Both the approaches based on using the newly created c_i dataframes, and that based on repeating the condition from the first line, don't seem to work.

Apologies for what might seem like an easy question, I'm fairly new to R and programming in general.

Thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Can you share some reproducbile data to work with? I do not know what 'dd' is

Comment: The data itself doesn't really matter in terms of what I'm trying to do, but my set called dd is simply simulated Uplift data produced by the sim_pte function in the Uplift package. So it has two binary variables y and treat, along with 5 random covariate variables X1 to X5 and a variable ts which represents the true lift. In this case, I had 1000 observations and am trying to to 10-fold CV, hence the *100 multiplier for my variable i in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reconsider building separate dataframes to flood your global environment and doing so with `assign`. Instead, build **two** lists of dataframes to hold your similarly structured 10 dataframes. And for the control/training split, use `split` on a group variable and the reverse using `by`.

```
# RESET ROW NAMES IF NOT NEEDED
row.names(dd) <- NULL      

# CREATE A GROUP COLUMN (MULTIPLES OF 100: df_0, df_100 ... df_900)
dd$grp <- paste0("df_", as.integer((as.integer(row.names(dd))-1) / 100) * 100)

# NAMED LIST OF df_0, df_100 ... df_900 (EACH NROWS = 100)
control_dflist <- split(dd, dd$grp)  # OR by(dd, dd$grp, identity)

# NAMED LIST OF df_0, df_100 ... df_900 (EACH NROWS = 900)
training_dflist <- by(dd, dd$grp, function(sub) subset(dd, grp!= max(sub$grp)))
```

Do note: you lose no functionality of dataframes if they are in named lists as opposed to separate objects.

```
head(control_dflist$df_0)        # 1ST CONTROL DF
summary(control_dflist$df_100)   # 2ND CONTROL DF
tail(control_dflist$df_200)      # 3RD CONTROL DF
```

To demo on random data:

```
set.seed(6222018)
dd <- data.frame(
  ID = replicate(1000, sample(seq(15), 1, replace=TRUE)),
  TOOL = replicate(1000, sample(c("julia","r","pandas","spss","stata","sas"), 1, replace=TRUE)),
  NUM = rnorm(1000)*100
)

control_dflist <- by(dd, dd$grp, identity)
training_dflist <- by(dd, dd$grp, function(sub) subset(dd, grp!= max(sub$grp)))
```

**Output** *(showing numbered and named reference; row names retained for illustration)*

```
head(control_dflist[[1]])
#   ID  TOOL        NUM  grp
# 1  4   sas   80.44873 df_0
# 2  5     r -204.50714 df_0
# 3  2  spss -111.54602 df_0
# 4  8 julia -145.48614 df_0
# 5  2   sas  103.82625 df_0
# 6  6  spss  -58.82708 df_0

head(training_dflist[[1]])
#     ID  TOOL       NUM    grp
# 101 10   sas -19.82463 df_100
# 102  4  spss  78.58277 df_100
# 103  2 stata  26.53858 df_100
# 104 13   sas 190.65434 df_100
# 105  1     r  36.96777 df_100
# 106 12     r 133.77021 df_100

tail(control_dflist$df_0)
#     ID  TOOL         NUM  grp
# 95   3 stata   13.446515 df_0
# 96   3  spss  171.488068 df_0
# 97  11   sas   48.573506 df_0
# 98  10     r -132.522866 df_0
# 99  12 stata -155.558407 df_0
# 100  2 stata    7.590873 df_0

tail(training_dflist$df_0)
#      ID  TOOL         NUM    grp
# 995   3  spss   92.613934 df_900
# 996  11  spss   13.389638 df_900
# 997  15 julia -147.108295 df_900
# 998   3 stata   91.032385 df_900
# 999   4   sas  -21.505796 df_900
# 1000 15   sas   -9.771332 df_900
```

Comment: Ooooh that's a clever solution. Never thought of making a group variable but that does work perfectly for my purposes. Thank you for the detailed answer and suggestions!